# Make flex wrap div scrollable and not exceed parents boundaries

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I wrote the problem statement into the codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-nova-z3kyj7?file=/src/App.tsx

I will repeat it here again

Goals:

1. make the blue container scrollable so that every white tile is reachable.
2. make the blue container not exceed the boundaries of the red container but still as big as possible (respect the margin)
3. make the blue container remain the same size regardless of the number of tiles it holds
   Things that are not allowed:
   1.No use of JS to calculate any dimensions
   2.No hardcoded values for any dimensions of the blue container or any wrappers of it

Answer (score 0):

First of all setting blue container display to flex makes to automatically grow and shrink depending on its children. So you can remove it first.We can align the children depending on your requirement, which is not mentioned.

To make the blue container use all the available place from it's parent you try as below.

```
red div style={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          height: "80vh",
          position : 'relative',
          width: "100vw",
          // overflow: "hidden"
        }}
blue div style={{
              // display: "flex",
              position : 'absolute',
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              margin: "1vh",
              height :'100%',
              width : '100%',
              overflow: "scroll"
            }}
```

If you have some other expectations let me know.